# How to correctly return an object instead of function with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a helper library for myself. Firstly I am wrapping like this:

```
(function (Helper, window, document) {
    var Helper = Helper || {};
    var type = function () {
        return {
            isObject: function (value) {
                return value !== null && Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object Object]";
            },
            isNumber: function (value) {
                return value !== null && Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object Number]" && !isNaN(value);
            },
            isString: function (value) {
                return value !== null && Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object String]";
            },
            isArray: function (value) {
                return value instanceof Array;
            },
            isFunction: function (value) {
                return typeof value === "function";
            },
            isDate: function (value) {
                return value instanceof(Date);
            },
            isRegExp: function (value) {
                return value instanceof RegExp;
            },
            isBoolean: function (value) {
                return value !== null && Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object Boolean]";
            },
            isError: function (value) {
                return value instanceof Error;
            },
            isNull: function (value) {
                return value === null;
            },
            isUndefined: function (value) {
                return typeof value === "undefined";
            }
        };
    };
    Helper.type = type;
})(Helper = window.helper || {}, window, document);
```

Now this works fine, but in order to reach the functions, I need to call a function like this Helper.type().isNumber(5) . How this should look so that it would return as object values, like this Helper.type.isNumber(5) ?

Comment: Could remove the function wrap `function() { ... }` on `var type = function(){...` then `var type = { isObject: ...`

Comment: or just execute function instant like  `var type = function () {...}()`

Comment: or just `Helper.type = type();`

Comment: mind though, that you are not adding functions to `Helper` but replacing, in case `window.helper` is undefined. You can use a far simpler pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/7d7mpx3c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning function reference:

```
Helper.type = type;
```

assign a function return value instead:

```
Helper.type = type();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `function()` wrapper from `type`:

```
(function (Helper, window, document) {
    var Helper = Helper || {};
    var type = {
        isObject: function (value) {
            return value !== null && Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object Object]";
        },
        ...
        isUndefined: function (value) {
            return typeof value === "undefined";
        }
    };
    Helper.type = type;
})(Helper = window.helper || {}, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply drop `function type(){` and `}; Helper.type = type;` and replace `return` with `Helper.type =`

```
(function(Helper, window, document) {

  Helper.type = {
    isNumber: function () {...}
  };


 })(Helper = window.helper || {}, window, document);
```

Comment: in case where `window.helper` is _undefined_ you nowhere assign it

Comment: yeah you do. You assign it to `window.Helper` (implicit global binding) or `var Helper` if its out there.

Comment: but OP is overwriting `Helper` with `helper` or `{}` which is not necessarily what he intends to do i guess.

Comment: in OP same error :-) anyway `window.helper` always _undefined_, because nowhere assigning